# HTML5 Banner Ad: Clicktag without URL

Tags: html, banner, double-click-advertising, clicktag

We recently built an HTML5 banner ad for a client and they came back to us asking why we did not add clicktag to the banner.

We were not provided a URL so so we did not add a clicktag.

Is it possible to add a clicktag without having a URL?

I added this to my link tag, but when I use [DoubleClick's](https://h5validator.appspot.com/dcm) validator, it still says the clicktag is missing.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open(clickTag);">
```

Here's what I added to remove the error, but this implies that I need a URL to add the clicktag. Please advise.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Change the value of this string to your URL
    var clickTag = "https://www.google.com/";
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "#" tag in URL to skip the error.

```
var clickTag = "#";
```